# shouldOverrideUrlLoading(...) not executed if "window.location.href" modified in a timeout callback

Tags: android, webview, webviewclient

I have a javascript function 'gotoMainPage()'

```
function gotoMainPage( ) {
    window.location.href = "main/main.do";
}
```

Now, WebViewClient's `shouldOverrideUrlLoading(..)` gets called if `gotoMainPage( )` is executed as a result of a 'direct user interaction', such as user clicking on this div:
 
`<div.... onclick='gotoMainPage();'/>`
However, if the execution is done via `setTimeout( gotoMainPage, 100 );` or via an `XMLHttpRequest` callback, `shouldOverrideUrlLoading(..)` is never called but the requested page is loaded into the webview.

Am I missing an obvious explanation or is this a bug?

Anyone?

Answer (score 6):

In my case, when using window.location = "http://xxx" in my webpage, the event shouldOverrideUrlLoading() is not triggered.

However, if I use a custom url scheme or protocol such as "androidurl://", shouldOverrideUrlLoading() is fired. My workaround would to be use a custom protocol and add the following code in the shouldOverrideUrlLoading() method:

```
if (url.startsWith("androidurl://")) {
    url = url.replaceAll("androidurl://", "http://");
}
```

This will change the custom protocol back to the "http://" protocol and you can handle the correct url from there.

This works for me.

Comment: great job. I was stuck with same issue for last 4 days. you saved me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

I've seen this come up myself as well, which imho, its clearly a bug.
Perhaps you can latch on to :

```
@Override
public void onLoadResource (WebView view, String url)
{

}
```

and/or

```
@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView webView, String url) 
{

}
```

I tried this myself, and found that onLoadResource would be triggered, even if shouldOverride wasnt.

Comment: I can confirm as well, both these methods are triggered even if shouldOverrideUrlLoading isn't